# Copying object values through reflections

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, reflection

I have written a class, for copying properties from one object to another, but I caught exception: 
System.Reflection.TargetException: The object does not match the target type. 
I checked, that **fromPropValue** is of correct type, is not null, etc.
Of course, property of recepient is Binary.

```
public class Reflector
{
    public void ReflectProperties(object from, object to) 
    { 
        Type toType = to.GetType();
        Type fromType = from.GetType();
        var toProperties = toType.GetProperties();

        foreach (var prop in toProperties)
        {
            var fromProp = fromType.GetProperty(prop.Name);

            if (fromProp != null)
            {
                var propType = prop.PropertyType;
                var fromPropValue = fromProp.GetValue(from, null);

                if (propType == typeof(Binary))
                    prop.SetValue(this, (Binary)fromPropValue, null); // <-- error
                else if (propType == typeof(string))
                    prop.SetValue(this, (string)fromPropValue, null);
                else if (propType == typeof(bool))
                    prop.SetValue(this, (bool)fromPropValue, null);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

P.S.: object **from** is parent of object **to**, and i want just to copy values of all properties from parent to child.

Comment: Are your `from` and `to` objects are of identical type? May be you could rewrite your method as `public void ReflectProperties<T>(T from, T to) { ... }` to ensure that the types of objects are identical.

Comment: @Andrew Sklyarevsky, no, **to** is child of **from**. Moreover, I wish to write universal method, applicable for any class.

Comment: Vasilij: Please avoid offensive abbreviations such as "WTF" in this forum. I've removed it from your question.

Comment: You should provide a data sample where it does not work so people can easily help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want `prop.SetValue(to, ...` instead of `prop.SetValue(this, ...`.

Also you don't need the `if` statements and the casts. You can just do `prop.SetValue(to, fromPropValue, null);`

Comment: Yeah! Sorry for bothering, stupid error. But I spent 3 hours to find what's up.

Comment: **if** statement comes from the attempts to find the reason of exception. I tried everything! :(